Dividing a circle into n equal arcs
In my engineering drawing lecture, my professor gave us a question where we had to divide a circle into n equal parts. (Basically dividing the circumference into n equal arcs such that whole of the circumference is utilized)
All constructions are to be done using an unmarked edge and a circle compass.
I tried thinking of constructing a regular polygon (n-sided) within the circle. For this, I had a solution given in the book "Engineering Drawing by N.D. Bhatt" which looks like this:

(Sorry for posting an image but I had to do that to show construction.)
But this does not provide an exact solution of what is needed. The error is less for smaller values of n but increases as n is increased. It increases to an extent that if n = 25, the circle falls short even to fit 24 parts.
If there exists some other method of dividing (other than inscribing a polygon) or some other method of inscribing a polygon (which gives exact results) then please do help.

I read the link you gave @heropup. That does use some Euclidian geometry in proving that the polygon can be constructed. But I wanna ask how is that actually done practically using an unmarked edge and a compass. Also I am a first year student (just joined the college) and this was the problem from our second lecture. So I am still new to a lot of things...

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon

This is bizarre. The construction doesn't even work for the example given, although it is very close in that case (the angle $AOC$ is around $71.95^\circ$, while it should of course be $72^\circ$). Interestingly, it works exactly for $n=3$, $n=4$ and $n=6$. Is the section in the book claiming that the construction is exact, or that it works approximately? Or is it perhaps asking you to find a flaw in the construction?

Euclid book 4: n-gons of $3, 4, 5, 6$ are demonstrated

@ChrisLewis The book neither claims the solution to be exact, nor do they deny it. They actually gave the problem and themselves gave the solution too.

@RobinSparrow Maybe. The original question asked by professor was actually to divide a semi-circle into 5 parts. So what I was looking for was to divide a circle into 10 parts (perhaps by constructing a decagon). But now I wonder how to do it for any value of n.

@UtkarshSahu: For draftsmanship, where you need only be within some tolerance and value quick/simple constructs, the professor's way is sensible. For exact construction, you will need other techniques. The Euclidean construct for 5-gon, for example, is of medium complexity. But, if truly by hand, the Euclidean construct will likely have as much or more error as the much simpler version of your professor (fewer steps = less cumulative error). Some regular n-gons cannot be constructed exactly with compass/straightedge, e.g., a 7-gon. If you want to learn exact constructs, start with Euclid.

@UtkarshSahu: I'll just note too that constructing regular n-gons works just like forming integers from primes. If you can form a 3-gon, and bisect, you can have 6-gon, 12-gon, 24-gon, etc. If you can form 3- and 5-gons you can form 15-gons etc. But if you lack a construction for some prime number of sides, all multiples of that factor are absent from your constructible n-gons.

Well @RobinSparrow that does make sense..
